# MultiDex stopped working Android

Tags: java, android

last night I was working on my app, initially I already reached my 64k limit so have had multidex for sometime now, sometimes it does fail and gives me a `ClassNotFoundException` but all I do is recompile my code and it works, if it fails I restart my computer but this time it is a different case, MultiDex seems to be excluding one of my classes which is funny because it was working until it suddenly stop, what it is doing it is excluding my `EnhancedGallery.class` which am using as my start activity, if I change to some other activity as start activity in manifest the App works until I try to run `EnhancedGallery` below are my Gradle Configurations

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "aubry.chromio.com.dressup"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),    'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
  }
   productFlavors {
   }
   sourceSets { main { res.srcDirs = ['src/main/res', '  src/main/res/layout_land'] } }



dexOptions {
    preDexLibraries = false
    javaMaxHeapSize "2g"
}

afterEvaluate {
    tasks.matching {
        it.name.startsWith('dex')
    }.each { dx ->
        if (dx.additionalParameters == null) {
            dx.additionalParameters = []
        }
        dx.additionalParameters += '--multi-dex'
        // dx.additionalParameters += "--main-dex-    list=$projectDir/dexFiles".toString()
    }
}
 }


dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:1.6.0@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
compile 'com.commit451:PhotoView:1.2.4'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'
compile 'com.wang.avi:library:1.0.0'
compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.1.0'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.5.0'
compile 'com.commonsware.cwac:camera:0.6.+'
compile project(':android-support-multidex')
compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:23.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:23.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.0'
compile 'com.github.ozodrukh:CircularReveal:1.1.0'
compile 'com.amulyakhare:com.amulyakhare.textdrawable:1.0.1'
compile 'com.oguzdev:CircularFloatingActionMenu:1.0.2'

 }
```

My **App.class** where I give gradle my app Context

```
import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.multidex.MultiDex;


 public class App extends Application {
 private static App instance;

 @Override public void onCreate() {
 super.onCreate();
 instance = this;

}

@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    super.attachBaseContext(base);
    MultiDex.install(this);
}

 public static App get() {
 return instance;
}


}
```

My Middle level Gradle file:

```
configurations.create("default")
artifacts.add("default", file('android-support-multidex.jar'))
```

And My top Level Gradle File:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

  buildscript {
   repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }


   }
   dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files

    // The Fabric Gradle plugin uses an open ended version to
    // react quickly to Android tooling updates
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
  }
}

 allprojects {
  repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
    }

    maven {
        url "https://s3.amazonaws.com/repo.commonsware.com"
    }
    maven {
        url 'http://dl.bintray.com/amulyakhare/maven'
    }
    maven {
        url "https://jitpack.io"
    }

  }
 }

 task clean(type: Delete) {
 delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**My error Report:**

```
1-14 09:25:49.430 30154-30154/aubry.chromio.com.dressup E/dalvikvm:  
Could not    find class 'android.support.v4.app.
NotificationCompat$Builder',  referenced from method     
com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.zza
11-14 09:25:49.431 30154-30154/aubry.chromio.com.dressup
E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity',   
referenced from method  
com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.zza
11-14 09:25:49.432 30154-30154/aubry.chromio.com.dressup E/dalvikvm: Could not  
find class 'android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity', referenced from method    
com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.zza
11-14 09:25:49.442 30154-30154/aubry.chromio.com.dressup E/dalvikvm: Could not  
find class 'android.app.AppOpsManager', referenced from method  
com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.zzb
11-14 09:25:49.518 30154-30154/aubry.chromio.com.dressup E/AndroidRuntime:  
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-14 09:25:49.518 30154-30154/aubry.chromio.com.dressup E/AndroidRuntime:  
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity  

ComponentInfo{aubry.chromio.com.dressup/aubry.chromio.com.dressup.activities.Enhan    cedGallery}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class  
"aubry.chromio.com.dressup.activities.EnhancedGallery" on path:  
 DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/aubry.chromio.com.dressup- 
 1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/aubry.chromio.com.dressup-1,  
 /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
 11-14 09:25:49.518 30154-30154/aubry.chromio.com.dressup E/AndroidRuntime:       
 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2269)
 11-14 09:25:49.518 30154-30154/aubry.chromio.com.dressup E/AndroidRuntime:      
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2395)
 11-14 09:25:49.518 30154-30154/aubry.chromio.com.dressup E/AndroidRuntime:      
 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:162)
 11-14 09:25:49.518 30154-30154/aubry.chromio.com.dressup E/AndroidRuntime:      
 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1364)
 11-14 09:25:49.518 30154-30154/aubry.chromio.com.dressup E/AndroidRuntime:      
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
 11-14 09:25:49.518 30154-30154/aubry.chromio.com.dressup E/AndroidRuntime:      
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
 11-14 09:25:49.518 30154-30154/aubry.chromio.com.dressup E/AndroidRuntime:     
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371)
 11-14 09:25:49.518 30154-30154/aubry.chromio.com.dressup E/AndroidRuntime:     
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 11-14 09:25:49.518 30154-30154/aubry.chromio.com.dressup E/AndroidRuntime:     
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
 11-14 09:25:49.518 30154-30154/aubry.chromio.com.dressup E/AndroidRuntime:       
 at    
  com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
 11-14 09:25:49.518 30154-30154/aubry.chromio.com.dressup E/AndroidRuntime:        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
11-14 09:25:49.518 30154-30154/aubry.chromio.com.dressup E/AndroidRuntime:       
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-14 09:25:49.518 30154-30154/aubry.chromio.com.dressup E/AndroidRuntime:  
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class    
"aubry.chromio.com.dressup.activities.EnhancedGallery" on path:   
 DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/aubry.chromio.com.dressup-  
1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/aubry.chromio.com.dressup-1,  
/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
11-14 09:25:49.518 30154-30154/aubry.chromio.com.dressup E/AndroidRuntime:      
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:53)
```

And lastly my **EnhancedGallery Class**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import #####.chromio.com.#####.R;
import #####.chromio.com.#####.polypicker.model.Image;
import #####.chromio.com.#####.polypicker.utils.ImageInternalFetcher;

 public class EnhancedGallery extends AppCompatActivity implements     
 View.OnScrollChangeListener{
 public ImageInternalFetcher mImageFetcher;
  private ImageGalleryAdapter mGalleryAdapter;
  private Set<Image> mSelectedImages;
  Display display;

Toolbar toolbar;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_enhanced_gallery);
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_transparent);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    mGalleryAdapter = new ImageGalleryAdapter(this);
    GridView galleryGridView = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.pp__gallery_grid);
    mSelectedImages = new HashSet<Image>();
    mImageFetcher = new ImageInternalFetcher(this, 500);

    Cursor imageCursor = null;
    try {
        final String[] columns = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.ORIENTATION};
        final String orderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_ADDED + " DESC";
        imageCursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, columns, null, null, orderBy);
        while (imageCursor.moveToNext()) {
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(imageCursor.getString(imageCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA)));
            int orientation = imageCursor.getInt(imageCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.ORIENTATION));
            mGalleryAdapter.add(new Image(uri, orientation));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if(imageCursor != null && !imageCursor.isClosed()) {
            imageCursor.close();
        }
    }


    galleryGridView.setAdapter(mGalleryAdapter);
    galleryGridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            Image image = mGalleryAdapter.getItem(i);
            if (!containsImage(image)) {
                //addImage(image);
            } else {
                //removeImage(image);
            }

            // refresh the view to
            // mGalleryAdapter.getView(i, view, adapterView);
            mGalleryAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });

}

@Override
public void onScrollChange(View view, int i, int i1, int i2, int i3) {

    toolbar.setAlpha(getAlphaforActionBar(view.getScrollY()));

}
private int getAlphaforActionBar(int scrollY) {
    int minDist = 0,maxDist = 650;
    if(scrollY>maxDist){
        return 255;
    }
    else if(scrollY<minDist){
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        int alpha = 0;
        alpha = (int)  ((255.0/maxDist)*scrollY);
        return alpha;
    }
}


class ViewHolder {
    ImageView mThumbnail;
    // This is like storing too much data in memory.
    // find a better way to handle this
    Image mImage;
}

public class ImageGalleryAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Image> {

    public ImageGalleryAdapter(Context context) {
        super(context, 0);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.enhanced_gallery_adapter, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.mThumbnail = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.pp__thumbnail_image);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        Image image = getItem(position);
        boolean isSelected = containsImage(image);

        convertView.setForeground(isSelected ? getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.gallery_photo_selected) : null);

        if (holder.mImage == null || !holder.mImage.equals(image)) {
            mImageFetcher.loadImage(image.mUri, holder.mThumbnail);
            holder.mImage = image;
        }
        return convertView;
    }
}
public boolean containsImage(Image image) {
    return mSelectedImages.contains(image);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            finish();
            return true;
        case R.id.action_settings:
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It has been a hustle, I finally fix it, or should I say found a way of bypassing it, since other classes were working I just created another class and copy pasted all my lines of code to the new class and it worked, I do not know the attachment between MultiDex and my EnhancedGallery class yet.